# Repeat read specific number of line into a text file, show them into a textboxes and save them

Tags: c#, textbox, text-files

I read a text file (8 lines), show them into a textbox and save them into a db. I already do it. But I need to continue to read the text files (8 lines everytime).

This is my code:

```
 var textBoxes = new List<TextBox> { textBox1, textBox2, textBox3, textBox4, textBox5, textBox6, textBox7, textBox8 };
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"saverisbex.txt"))
        {
            int incNumber = 0;
            string nyNumber = incNumber.ToString("00");
            incNumber++;

            textBox9.Text = incNumber.ToString();

            int lineNumber = 0;
            int lastGroup = 0;
            string line;
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                int currentGroup = lineNumber / 8;
                if (lastGroup != currentGroup)
                {
                    conn.Open();



                    SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand("", conn);

                    comando.CommandText = "insert into finabex (Id,home,away,homescoresft,awayscoresft,oddhome,oddx,oddaway,date) values ('" +
                        textBox9.Text + "', '" +
                        textBox1.Text + "', '" +
                        textBox2.Text + "', '" +
                        textBox3.Text + "', '" +
                        textBox4.Text + "', '" +
                        textBox5.Text + "', '" +
                        textBox6.Text + "', '" +
                        textBox7.Text + "', '" +
                        textBox8.Text + "')";


                    comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    MessageBox.Show("Saved!");
                    conn.Close();
                }
                int textBoxNumber = lineNumber % 8;
                textBoxes[textBoxNumber].Text = line;


                lastGroup = currentGroup;
                lineNumber++;
            }
        }
```

so, I read my first 8 lines (0-7), now I need to continue (8-15), (16-23) and so on.

I hope you can help me. Thanks everybody!!! :D

Comment: Read the entire file into the list and do the processing from there 8 lines at a time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the integer division and `%`-operators. Put all your textboxes into a collection:

```
var textBoxes = new List<TextBox> { textBox1, textBox2, textBox3, textBox4, textBox5, textBox6, textBox7, textBox8 };

using(var conn = new SqlConnection("Connectionstring"))
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"saverisbex"))
{
    int lineNumber = 0;
    int lastGroup = 0;
    string line;
    conn.Open(); // before the loop not in loop
    while((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        int currentGroup = lineNumber / 8;
        if (lastGroup != currentGroup)
        {
            // presuming that ID is the primary key and an identity column which auto generates its value on insert
            string insertSQL = @"insert into finabex (home,away,homescoresft,awayscoresft, oddhome,oddx,oddaway,date) 
                                 values (@home,@away,@homescoresft,@awayscoresft,@oddhome,@oddx,@oddaway,@date)";
            using (var comando = new SqlCommand(insertSQL, conn))
            {
                comando.Parameters.Add("@home", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox9.Text;
                comando.Parameters.Add("@away", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox1.Text;
                comando.Parameters.Add("@homescoresft", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox2.Text;
                comando.Parameters.Add("@awayscoresft", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox3.Text;
                comando.Parameters.Add("@oddhome", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox4.Text;
                comando.Parameters.Add("@oddx", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox5.Text;
                comando.Parameters.Add("@oddaway", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox7.Text;
                DateTime date;
                if (!DateTime.TryParse(textBox8.Text, out date))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Not a valid date: " + textBox8.Text);
                    continue;
                }
                comando.Parameters.Add("@date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = date;
                int insertedCount = comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            // ...
        }
        int textBoxNumber = lineNumber % 8;
        textBoxes[textBoxNumber].Text = line;
        // ...
        lastGroup = currentGroup;
        lineNumber++;
    }
}
```

So `linenumber=0` is in `groupOf8=0` until `linenumber=7`, then `groupOf8=1` and so on.

Note that i have used the `using`-statement on all objects that implement `IDisposable` to ensure that all unmanaged resources are disposed property(even in case of error).

**Also use sql parameters to prevent sql-injection, always.**

Comment: I tried in this way:
http://pastebin.com/nAy8h47a

but I got error here: "matrix index out of limit" in textBox6.Text = line[5].ToString();
what can I do, please? :)

Comment: @marcellogabrielli: what are you trying to do? `line` is a single line of the file, so you cannot use `line[0].ToString()` since that would only take the first character of the line.

Comment: I need to insert 8 lines into a 8 textbox at the same time, and continue to do it to the end of the textfile 
e.g.
0-7 lines, 8-15 lines,16-23 lines and so on

Comment: @marcellogabrielli: how many textboxes do you have? Do you want to insert line 0-7 into textbox1-8 and line 8-15 into textbox9-16 and line 16-23 into textboxes17-24 and so on?

Comment: No, I think to do in this way:
line 0-7 into textbox1-8 and save them into db; clear textbox 1-8
line 8-15 into textbox1-8 and save them into db; clear textbox 1-8
line 16-23 into textbox1-8 and save them into db; clear textbox 1-8
I know how can I save them but I don't know how can put others lines in the same textbox till the end of text files :)

Comment: I am so sorry but I am a newbie about C#. I edited my first post with the final code, but I got error about primary key. There is some problem to increment it and I tried to set a count (you can see in the code), but it doesn't work...can you help me please? :)  thanks!

Comment: @marcellogabrielli: if it is a primary key, is it an identity-column which auto generates it's value? I would suggest to do so. Then you don't need to generate one yourself which is in danger to fail on race conditions.